# Is it possible to test in javascript if var contains an image node and if it is loaded?

Tags: javascript

I'm passing Node selections from function to function or function to Object and I'd like to check a few things in from the parameters of the second one.

I think I should check for it to be a Node, then the property tagName to be set to IMG but the loaded seems to be more dificult, as it is an image coming from the site and may or may not be loaded.

```
function is_tag_img_loaded (img) {
    if(img.tagname == "IMG" && img.loadended){
        return true;
    }else{ return false; }
}
```

Comment: If your question is whether it is possible the answer is *yes*. What exactly is your problem? Side note: You don’t need the if: `return img.tagname == "IMG" && img.loadended`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tagname check is fine. You can use [`img.complete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) to see if it is loaded (and valid).